# Doctrine entity form type onetomany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a user class that has a onetomany self-referencing relationship (ancestor and decendents). And I have an invoice class, which references two users based on the ancestor-decendents relationship. Meaning that, a user creates an invoice, so the form's "from" property will have the logged in user, while the form's "to" property should be a selection from the logged in user's decendets. 
This is the invoice's buildForm method

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('createdDate')
        ->add('from')
        ->add('to', 'entity', array('class' => 'Disty\SystemBundle\Entity\User'))
    ;
}
```

To keep it short, I want to somehow only show options of decendent users. Right now it shows all users registered.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [the *query_builder* parameter that should do the trick](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) you can find `query_builder` option of the `entity` form type. So you just need to modify query builder to retrieve only users which belong to the current logged in user.